# How to force my app to be always fullscreen

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

Have you ever seen the ipads next to each product on the Apple stores? they are displaying tech specs of the product and its not possible to leave that screen even if you press the home button its just not possible to get out of it, its always on full screen on top of everything... I want to do the same for one application I am working on, I wont need to publish it in the app store so that wont be an issue but I am not sure how to accomplish this task or if its even possible... any suggestions?

thanks!

Comment: According to what I know, there's no way to do this. Even if you can do it, your app will be rejected by Apple.

Comment: @BlueSmith Time to click the link to the dupe. They enumerate at least two solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your link, @H2CO3, but it's not the answer.

Comment: @BlueSmith: OP says "I won't need to publish it in the app store"; Apple's policies are [off topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131388/would-questions-about-app-store-approval-be-appropriate-for-so) in general here and irrelevant to the technical question anyways.

Comment: hey guys could you add the link to the duplicate question? I cant seem to find it... thanks all for the answers

Comment: nevermind just saw link... sorry all... I need a coffee haha